# How to make an edit form for a one-to-one relationship?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have two models with a one-to-one relationship, say a Person and a Hat. The foreign key is in Person so Person belongsTo Hat and Hat hasOne Person.

Now in the create form for Person I can just use a custom find() to find all Hats that are not taken already and the automagic will populate a combobox with all available Hats for me.

But how do I design the edit form for a Person? Here I would like a combobox with all available Hats plus the currently chosen Hat (if not null), with the current Hat as default choice.

I haven't worked with Cake for a while so I might be missing something obvious, or is the problem in the design?

Comment: Kindly share some code so that I can help you.

Comment: Well that's the thing, I don't know how to code it. I can get a list of all Hats in the controller (with Hat->find('all')) and use $this->Form->input('hat_id') in the edit view for a Person, but this give me a list of all Hats (some might be taken by others already). But if I do a custom find/query to return only available Hats the Hat that is currently chosen for the Person being edited will not be in the list. Do I need to do a query for all Hats not worn by a Person or worn by the current Person, and then in the view figure out manually which option should be default in the combobox?

Answer (score 0):

Person Model:

```
class Person extends AppModel
{
    public $name = 'Person';
    public $belongsTo = array('Hat' => array('className' => 'Hat',
                              'foreignKey' => 'hat_id'));
}
```

Hat Model:

```
class Hat extends AppModel
{
    public $name = 'Hat';
    public $hasOne = array('Person' => array('className' => 'Person',
                                             'foreignKey' => 'hat_id'));
}
```

All Available hats that are not assigned to anyone:

```
$avaiable_hats = $this->Hat->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Person.hat_id <> ' => 'Hat.id')));
```

All assigned hats

```
$assigned_hats = $this->Person->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Person.hat_id IS NOT NULL',
                                                                        'Person.hat_id <> 0')));
```

If you want to make a combobox list, use the following:

All Available hats options that are not assigned to anyone

```
$available_hats_options = $this->Hat->find('list', array('conditions' => array('Person.hat_id <> ' => 'Hat.id'),
                                                        'fields' => array('Hat.id', 'Hat.hat_name')));
```

And you can make the dropdown list in your view using the following syntax:

```
$this->Form->input('available_hats', array('options' => $available_hats_options, 'div' => false, 'label' => 'Available Hats'));
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this does not make sense to me. Are you saying that one should have a foreign key in _both_ tables? And then query Hats on the condition that the related Person has a hat_id matching the Hats id to find available Hats? What would it mean if the foreign keys did not match (Hat A refereces Person X while Person X references Hat B)? I fail to see how this would even work, and it can hardy produce a combobox with available Hats and current Hat.

Comment: No, you just have to define a single foreign key in persons table i.e. `hat_id`

Comment: Your Hat model includes a person_id though. And if you only have one foreign key in Person finding unassigned Hats would be fairly easy. Also you query to find assigned Hats would return people not hats, right? In any case, I still cannot see that the combobox would include the current hat.